# Issue reading from sscanf

Tags: c, char, handle

All this is probably a real simple one but I am missing something and hope you can help. Ok this is my issue as simple as I can put it.

I am returning a buffer from `readfile` after using a USB device. This all works ok and I can out put the buffer fine by using a loop like so

```
for (long i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)  //for all chars in string
{
    unsigned char c = buffer[i];

    switch (Format)
    {
        case 2:         //hex
            printf("%02x",c);
        break;
        case 1:         //asc
            printf("%c",c);
        break;
    }  //end of switch format
}
```

When I use the text (`%c`) version I can see the data in the buffer in my screen the I way I expected it. However my issue is when I come to read it using `sscanf`. I use `strstr` to search some key in the buffer and use `sscanf` to retrieve its data. However, `sscanf` fails. What could be the problem?

Below is an example of the code I am using to scan the buffer and it works fine with this standalone version. Buffer section in the above code can't be read. Even though I can see it with `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <windows.h> 

int main () 
{ 
    // in my application this comes from the handle and readfile
    char buffer[255]="CODE-12345.MEP-12453.PRD-222.CODE-12355" ;    
    //
    int i; 
    int codes[256];  
    char *pos = buffer;  
    size_t current = 0;  
    //  
    while ((pos=strstr(pos, "PRD")) != NULL) {  
        if (sscanf(pos, "PRD - %d", codes+current))  
            ++current;  
        pos += 4;  
    }  

    for (i=0; i<current; i++) 
        printf("%d\n", codes[i]); 
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you _return buffer from readfile_ ?

Comment: ReadFile(h,buffer,0x224,&read,NULL);

Comment: and also the loop to test its working added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, your `ReadFile` is giving you non-printable characters before the data you are interested in, specifically with a `'\0'` in the beginning. Since strings in C are NUL-terminated, all standard functions assume there is nothing in the buffer.

I don't know what it is exactly that you are reading, but perhaps you are reading a message that contains a header? In such a case you should skip the header first.

Blindly trying to solve the problem, you can skip the bad characters manually, assuming they are all in the beginning.

First of all, let's make sure the buffer is always NUL-terminated:

```
char buffer[1000 + 1];    // +1 in case it read all 1000 characters
ReadFile(h,buffer,0x224,&read,NULL);
buffer[read] = '\0';
```

Then, we know that there are `read` number of bytes filled by `ReadFile`. We first need to go back from that to find out where the good data start. Then, we need to go further back and find the first place where the data is not interesting. Note that, I am assuming in the end of the message, there are no printable characters. If there are, then this gets more complicated. In such a case, it is better if you write your own `strstr` that doesn't terminate on `'\0'`, but reads up to a given length.

So instead of

```
char *pos = buffer;
```

We do

```
// strip away the bad part in the end
for (; read > 0; --read)
    if (buffer[read - 1] >= ' ' && buffer[read - 1] <= 126)
        break;
buffer[read] = '\0';
// find where the good data start
int good_position;
for (good_position = read; good_position > 0; --good_position)
    if (buffer[good_position - 1] < ' ' || buffer[good_position - 1] > 126)
        break;
char *pos = buffer + good_position;
```

The rest can remain the same.

Note: I am going from the back of the array, because assuming the beginning is a header, then it may contain data that might be interpreted as printable characters. On the other hand, in the end it may be all zeros or something.

Comment: Thanks the code works ok as it is my issue is when I remove the maually entered line and allow it to read the buffer it wont read even though my snippet below is the same as the buffer readout.  
char buffer[255]="CODE-12345.MEP-12453.PRD-222.CODE-12355" ; mine just comes from the handle.

Comment: @user1539199, do you know exactly where the code fails? Is it in `strstr` or `sscanf`? Also, is `buffer` NUL-terminated? If so, what happens if you `printf` it (instead of character by character as you have done before)?

Comment: the strstr part is failing which is doesnt if I insert my line which must mean the format of the buffer needs to change? or I am doing this the wrong way.

Comment: If in your original code `buffer` is defined as `char buffer[<size>]`, no you don't need to change the format. Try `printf("%s\n", pos)` right before the `strstr` in your original code and tell me what you see.

Comment: Also, when you say it doesn't work, is it that it gives the wrong output, or maybe it crashes?

Comment: Thanks when i tryed printf("%s\n", pos); it shows no output at all. so its like it cant read the buffer strange as this works in the loop just below.

Comment: @user1539199, are you sure you have this line in your original code also: `char *pos = buffer;`? You could also try `printf("%s\n", buffer);`. It would be easier if you put the original code, from between the `switch` and `strstr` so I can inspect it.

Comment: Ok I have added the code above still seems the buffer isnt passed properly as the loop can display it.

Comment: So you tell me that the `for` loop with the `switch` inside works fine? Can you print the value of `read`? What is it? Also, can you print using `Format = 2`, to better inspect the contents of the `buffer`?

Comment: As you can see, there are some random characters in the beginning of the buffer. Specifically, there is `'\0'` in the beginning of the buffer, which means to all string functions the buffer is empty. That is why neither `printf` nor `strstr` go beyond that initial NUL. Do you know why you are reading this? I will change my answer to tell you how to skip it, but you can post another question asking why you get the corrupted data.

Comment: Thanks I tried that the output is still putting out the original charactors. Your correct there headers from a function that was called in a loader on the arm device. Chopping them is not a problem as the data needed is just past them. Is there a way to shave the data both ends. or move all non text from string?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't really understand your last comment. My correction just moves the `pos` pointer without touching the buffer. So your printout of the whole buffer should not change. What _would_ change is `printf("We getting for pos %s\n", pos);` in which you should now be able to see some output. If you give me the value of `read`, it would help. I have a suspicion that you also have bad data _after_ the good code. So you may need to do the stripping from both ends.

Comment: Ok I'm going to add that part also.

Comment: Thanks for all your help that didnt work though I will look at just removing the illegal charactors from the string somehow. I have voted for you on here and so glad you helped me :-)

Comment: @user1539199, no problem, it was an interesting question.